# Multi Part Identifier Can Not be Bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble getting past this error. I'm using SQL Server 2017 (v14):

> The multi-part identifier "PS_FFC.Date" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "PS_FFC.Date: could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "PS_FFC.Employee ID" could not be bound.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    [Employee ID],
    (SELECT SUM(Total) AS Expr1
     FROM dbo.PS_FFC
     WHERE (PS_FFC.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 1)))
       AND (PS_FFC.Date < GETDATE())
     GROUP BY PS_FFC.[Employee ID]) AS Current_Month_FFCs,
    (SELECT SUM(Total) AS Expr2
     FROM dbo.PS_FFC AS PS_FFC_2
     WHERE (PS_FFC.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 2))) 
       AND (PS_FFC.Date < EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 1))
     GROUP BY PS_FFC.[Employee ID]) AS Prior_Month_FFCs
FROM 
    dbo.PS_FFC AS PS_FFC_1
```

The table I'm pulling from looks like:

```
Employee ID|    Date|         FFC
Emp000          1/1/2019      1
Emp000          1/2/2019      2
Emp000          12/31/2019    1
Emp001          1/3/2019      1
Emp003          1/20/2019     2
Emp004          2/5/2019      4
```

This what I'm hoping for the result to look like:

```
Employee ID|    Current_Month_FFCs|    Prior_Month_FFCs
Emp000          0                      3
Emp001          0                      1  
Emp003          0                      2
Emp004          4                      0
```

Comment: My psychic abilities are failing me.  The error you are getting is.....?

Comment: Apologies - adding now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second subquery is using the alias PS_FFC_2 for the table and you're referencing as PS_FFC.
The good thing is that you don't need the subqueries for this and you can simply use a CASE expression to aggregate only the rows you need.

```
SELECT PS_FFC.[Employee ID],
    SUM( CASE WHEN PS_FFC.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 1)) AND PS_FFC.Date < GETDATE()
                    THEN PS_FFC.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Current_Month_FFCs,
    SUM( CASE WHEN PS_FFC.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 2)) AND PS_FFC.Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 1))
                    THEN PS_FFC.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Prior_Month_FFCs
FROM  dbo.PS_FFC AS PS_FFC
WHERE  PS_FFC.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 2)) 
AND PS_FFC.Date < GETDATE()
GROUP BY Employee_ID;
```

Comment: I'm a big fan for case statements so this seems ideal however now I'm getting a new error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Comment: I'm sorry, since I didn't test it, I didn't realized that I had misplaced the WHERE clause. As you should know, it was supposed to go before the GROUP BY. I fixed it now.

Comment: This one worked, I just needed to move GROUP BY below WHERE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your second subquery you aliased `PS_FFC`as `PS_FFC_2`. To address it's columns use the alias e.g. `PS_FFC_2.Date` not the original name (e.g. `PS_FFC.Date`). Or don't alias the table.

Comment: Thats worked. But now I'm getting a new error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=.... or when the subquery is used as an expression

Answer (score 0):

Once you alias a table, you have to use the alias.   You failed to do so in your second subquery:

```
                     (SELECT        SUM(Total) AS Expr2
                       FROM            dbo.PS_FFC AS PS_FFC_2
                       WHERE        (PS_FFC.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 2))) AND (PS_FFC.Date < EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 1))
                       GROUP BY PS_FFC.[Employee ID]) AS Prior_Month_FFCs
```

should be:

```
                     (SELECT        SUM(Total) AS Expr2
                       FROM            dbo.PS_FFC AS PS_FFC_2
                       WHERE        (PS_FFC_2.Date >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 2))) AND (PS_FFC_2.Date < EOMONTH(GETDATE(), - 1))
                       GROUP BY PS_FFC_2.[Employee ID]) AS Prior_Month_FFCs
```